# Firestore Rules > Determine which collection / rule is failing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is there any way to see the specific collection / rule that is failing in Firestore? I've looked in firestore-debug.log (running on localhost) as well as in the Firebase UI. Firestore logs the error to the console, but does not include the information I need to debug the permissions:

[image: Console Error Output]

Comment: Please do not show pictures of text.  On Stack Overflow, it's better to copy the text into the question itself so it's easier to read and search.

Answer (score 3):

Firebase intentionally does not disclose information about what rule is failing, as it would give malicious users information you don't want them to have.

The best information is typically available in the emulator in the Firebase console, which tells you what specific rule has failed.

Answer (score 1):

Error messages delivered to the client SDK will never show the root cause of the rejection, as that would reveal something about the security measure to a potential attacker.

If you want to test and debug your security rules locally before you deploy, you can use the Firebase emulator suite to get detailed information about how your rules are working with client code that would make queries against them.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator
https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/emulator-setup

Comment: yeah, i was hoping for a log somewhere. i have a test suite with everything passing using the emulator locally but something is getting blocked.

Comment: The local rules emulator will log pretty extensively what happened.  You can also use the `debug(x)` function to make it dump the value of `x` at any time (which also returns `x` so you can keep using it in an expression).

Comment: being able to unit test the security rules was priceless, but the problem is something outside the scope of my tests...having trouble figuring out exactly what it is though. it would be ideal to have a rule error log on the Firebase UI like they have with cloud functions. This would be helpful for troubleshooting as well as monitoring malicious activity.

Comment: Please file a feature request for anything you feel is missing.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support