# Determine path and root cause of FirebaseError Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm using Firebase and Firestore. My web app was throwing an error when rendering:

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions
```

but the stacktrace is very long and all library code as far as I can tell, making it nearly impossible to determine what code is actually causing this.

After lots of hunting through my code base I determined that a library was trying to fetch data from `/profiles/{uid}`, and fixed the error, but if I had some better debugging tools this would have been  much faster.

Is there a way to get the path that was attempting to be read from the error, or any other metadata related to the error? I checked monitoring and logs in Firebase web console but couldn't find anything. A log of Firestore denies, including the attempted path would be very helpful for this purpose.

Comment: A query is failing due to security rules that deny it.  Please edit the question to show the query and the relevant security rules.  Without these details, there's nothing we can do.

Comment: I understand why the query was failing. That is not the question I'm asking. The question is how to determine the path of the failed query using monitoring or logging or better error descriptions. I'm happy to rephrase the question or add details, but do please do not vote to close my question without understanding what the question is. Thanks.

Comment: I've been searching for this but I couldn't find anything. I believe this is more of an issue with the used language than another thing, as the executing environment should be in charge of showing you a stacktrace.

Comment: It would be helpful to know how you're calling your firebase functions (e.g. show your code!). Is the error showing in your question from task.getException()?

Comment: What I'm hoping for is to find some kind of list of denies in Firebase or Google Cloud's monitoring capabilities, so the code is mostly irrelevant. I found deny count, but not any other info, like the path that was denied. In this case I'm using the Web APIs with React Redux Firestore. In this particular case, it was [this config](https://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/recipes/profile.html#profile-in-firestore) that caused the error from library code, as it was trying to access `/users/{uid}`, but this question isn't about this particular instance of the error.

Comment: Just here to support the substance of question. It's not impossible for there to be, e.g. a race condition in some async app logic where authentication changes before a db request is triggered -- better understanding what exactly triggered the permission error could cut debugging time significantly.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58807923/10810527) by Doug Stevenson there's no way of logging this since it may reveal security measures to a potential attacker.

Still, you should find more logs if you use [the local emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator) to test your queries before deploying.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking more about server-side logging and monitoring provided by Google Cloud Platform.